# Have to select ruby version I want to use whenevr I open a new terminal and check ruby version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, passenger, centos7, centos6

I have installed ruby 2.2.1,1.9.3, 2.2.x via rvm in CentOS 7.2 , But when I open another terminal and run `ruby -v`, its say `bash: ruby: command not found`.
Then again I have to set which ruby rvm is using by

```
rvm use 2.2.1 --default
```

please suggest the changes required , so there is no need to set which ruby rvm is using after opening new terminal .

Answer (score 0):

Add `.ruby-version` file in the root folder of your project with the following contents

**/.ruby-version**

```
2.2.1
```

Also, you might want to change the following in your terminal setting

```
Preferences > Profiles > Command > Check "Run command as a login shell"
```

Comment: where to get  .ruby-version file

Comment: create a new file with filename `.ruby-version`

Comment: what should be its extension (.rb,.txt) , and please tell me what should I write inside the file.

Comment: no extension just `.ruby-version` and the contents will be just `2.2.1`